# HttpPostedFileBase me devuelve null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un proyecto web en ASP.NET MVC, cuento con un formulario que tiene que hacer una subida de una imagen, para ello estoy usando [HttpPostedFileBase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase?view=netframework-4.8), realizo su llamada con el siguiente código:

Vista:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Imagenes, new { style = "height: 50px; font-size:21px;", autocomplete = "off", type = "file", name = "Imagenes" })
```

Modelo:

```
public class ArticuloVm
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase Imagenes { get; set; }
}
```

Controlador:

```
vm.Imagenes.SaveAs(Path.Combine(@"e:temp", Path.GetFileName(vm.Imagenes.FileName)));
```

Al tratar de obtenerlo en el controlador, mi resultado es null, mirando en SOeng encontré un [problema similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551528/httppostedfilebase-always-return-null-in-asp-net-mvc), el cual hace hincapié en que ha de llamarse todo igual, he comprobado si es así en el mio, todo tiene el mismo nombre, `Imagenes`, pero sigo obteniendo null.

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal y cómo puedo solucionarlo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La Solución que he encontrado es añadir un método AJAX que, en el POST ataque al controlador:

```
$('#aceptarPost').click(function () {

            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $("#Imagenes").get(0).files;
            // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
            if (files.length > 0) {
                data.append("Imagenes", files[0]);
            }
            // Make Ajax request with the contentType = false, and procesDate = false
            var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FileUpload",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data
            });

            ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
                // Do other operation
            }); 
    });
```

Y creando en el controlador un `ActionResult` con:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase Imagenes)
        {
            if (Imagenes != null && Imagenes.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Img"), Path.GetFileName(Imagenes.FileName));
                Imagenes.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            return View();
        }
```